# Solr - Reindex recommended batch size

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I've just installed Solr on my Rails application (using sunspot).

I want solr to re-index a couple of columns on one of my tables, the tables is pretty big (~50M records).

What is the recommended batch size to use? currently i'm using 1000 and its running for over a day.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch size is not that important, 1000 is probably OK, though I wouldn't go any larger than that. It depends on the size of the documents, how many bytes of text are indexed for each one.

Are you committing after each batch? That can be slow. I load a 23M document index with a single commit at the end. The documents are small, the metadata for books, and it takes about 90 minutes. To get that speed, I needed to use a single SQL query for the load. Using any subqueries made it about 10X slower.

I'm using the JDBC support in the DataInputHandler, though I may move to some custom code that makes a DB query and submits batches.

I've heard that the CSV input handler is very efficient, so it might work to dump your data to CSV, then load it with that handler.